# How to get notifications in background and data synchronization

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, background-process

I have here some requirements and now I want to check if these requirements are possible and how they could be reached. It is about notifications and running in background:

- The app should show notifications if new data is available and the app is in background (if the app is not running there should be no notifications)
- Also the app should synchronize the data so that the data is up-to-date
- The user should be able to choose an interval when the synchronization should take place (5 seconds, 30 seconds, ...)
- The app should run on iOS 6 and above.

**Notifications:**
The problem with *local notifications* is that you only can set seconds, minutes, hours ... as interval. It is not possible to set a custom interval. But this type would only be appropriate if I have a background task, which searches for updates and if an update is available, it immediatetly displays a local notification.

*Remote notifications* on the other side needs an additional server for the notifications. Also the port 5223 has to be open to receive the notifications (but most of the time cellular network is used and here the port should be open). How many remote notifications can be send and presented to the user? For local notifications it is 64.

**Running in background:**
Only in iOS 7 `Background Fetch` and `Remote Notficiations` are available. The problem with the `Background Fetch` is that only small data should be transferred and the OS determines when the app gets a timeslot (own algorithm which learns from the user). Sources reports a max. execution time from 30 seconds, but I didn't found an official statement from Apple.

`Remote Notifications` also seems to need a provider. But here the user would get a notification and the app could download/sync the new data in background (again max. 30 seconds).

What about iOS 6?

Another option would be to let the app run in background / have a background thread which checks for updates/synchronize at a certain intervall and than creates a local notification. But how long does the app run in background? I read about 5 seconds which would be to short.

And another one would be to use push notifications and if the user starts the app it does the synchronization process.

`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` seems not to suite here for my case.

How would I get notifications when running in background together with synchronization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you probably know, backgrounding on iOS is rather limited. iOS will not let your application just run in background indefinitely. If you use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`, your app will get some background runtime (10 minutes on iOS 6, 3 minutes on iOS 7), but you can't "renew" that time while app is still background. Thus, your second option ("let the app run in background / have a background thread which checks for updates/synchronize at a certain interval") isn't practical unless you are willing to abuse other backgrounding modes (which is likely to fail AppStore review process).

Starting from iOS 7 it became possible to send "silent" push notifications (i.e. ones having `content-available` set), e.g. notifications that will be delivered directly to the app (instead of displaying alert and only launching app only when user confirms it). This makes important difference for backgrounding and is quite convenient actually. Whenever your app receives such push notification, it can check for new data, sync data, etc (you get around 30 seconds of runtime). Apple claims to throttle "silent" push notifications, but not much details on this. In my practice sending them every 15 minutes seem to work.

You may argue that 30 seconds is way to little to sync data. That's true. To solve this iOS 7 introduced background downloads and uploads that you can initiate via `NSURLSession` configured with  `[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:]`. Download/upload will then be handled by the system and once it completes your app will be woken to handle it.

To the best of my knowledge this is the best approach you can take for regular data synchronisation from background apps. This won't work for iOS 6, though.

Alternatively, if your server can decide if new data is available and if user should be alerted, traditional push notifications should be sufficient. In this case there's no need for your app to run in background and check for new data (server can do this and send remote notification with an alert/sound). This will obviously work on iOS 6, too.

Comment: If I use silent push notification can I inform the user that new data is available? E.g. syncing in the background and than create a local notification? With a silent notification the user doesn't know that an update is available? Or should I send another regular notification?
For iOS 7 I could use `Remote Notifications` with silent push notifications. For iOS 6 I use the regular notifications, but here the user has to start the app and than the app could fetch the new data. Am I right?

Comment: Documentation on `presentLocalNotificationNow:` suggests that you can present local notifications from background. "Silent" notifications are a way for your app to be woken up and do some work in background; they do not produce any alert or prompt. With iOS 6 this approach will not work as your app will not be woken up, so you have to come up with alternative solution.

Comment: OK I think I got it. For iOS 7 I can use the background feature with `Remote Notifications` or `Silent Remote Notificaitons` (perhaps presenting a notification). The iOS 6 version cannot run in background and therefore I can only use push notifications (and on app start I make the sync).

Comment: Have you tried `Background Fetch`? Would it be possible to use this together with `NSURLSession` and `presentLocalNotificationNow`? Then I woundn't need an additional server ... Would I get a timeslot even if it takes longer? How often would I get a timeslot? Would the app pass the Appstore Review guidelines?

Comment: `Background Fetch` doesn't give you control on when iOS will wake your app: with "silent" notifications your server decides when to wake the app, with fetch iOS decides this. Other than that, it should work very similar and let you schedule/present local notification. Timeslot is also ~30 sec, not sure how often iOS will wake the app though.